# Creating xml file in Python that lists all files in a given directory

Tags: python, xml, directory-listing

I'm given a directory, and I have to write a python script that creates an xml file that includes all the .xml files in that directory.

For example, say /tmp/ contains the following xml files:

```
beans.xml
cakes.xml
donuts.xml
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script that creates the following xml:

```xml
<root>
   <include file="/tmp/beans.xml"/>
   <include file="/tmp/cakes.xml"/>
   <include file="/tmp/donuts.xml/>
</root>
```

This is what I've pieced together so far, but it overwrites the file tag each time so only donuts.xml is included

```py
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder
import glob
import os

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
ROOT = E.root
DOC = E.include

os.chdir("/tmp/")
for f in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    the_doc = ROOT(

    DOC(file=f)

)

print lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True)
```

This is the output of my script as it is right now:

```
<root>
    <include file="/tmp/donuts.xml"/>
</root>
```

How do I keep beans.xml and cakes.xml form being overwritten?

Comment: how do I keep beans.xml and cakes.xml from being overwritten, sorry

Comment: Don't post a correction as a comment, EDIT the original post!

Comment: gotcha, sorry I'm fairly new here

Comment: Not a problem, part of the learning curve :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `the_doc` in each iteration. That's why your output has only one element. Try with this:

```
os.chdir("/tmp/")
files = [DOC(file=f) for f in glob.glob("*.xml")]
the_doc = ROOT(*files)
print lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! So you created a list of the xml files in the directory and then the_doc = ROOT(*files) points to each item in the list?

Comment: @user1420913 Exactly, `ROOT(*files)` [unpacks the list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) of files. `ROOT(*[f1,f2,f3])` and `ROOT(f1, f2, f3)` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about lxml, but reading the documentation leads to this solution:

```
import os
import glob
from lxml import etree

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = etree.Element('root')
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    for filename in glob.glob('*.xml'):
        root.append(etree.Element('include', file=filename))

    print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True) # Or, print to a file if you wish
```